# Redux-Toolkit Query Authorization cases

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

Anybody used RTKQ for auth purposes? Successfully got signup and login working. But can’t figure out how to save the token  that is fired back. Tried default useBaseQuery with prepareHeaders as in official docs and it simply returns 'can’t read properties of undefined' on token from redux store. I believe I need to pass credentials on submit, but can't find proper way to do that.

My slice and component: [GIST-LINK](https://gist.github.com/LeroViten/150d7423de4259bd2fdd27f9fb17e7c3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation examples show holding your authentication information on a separate slice outside of your api slice - putting it there with manual code and taking it from there with manual code.

From what it looks like in your code example, you are just trying to read `state.authApi.data.token` in the hopes that that data would somehow "be there" without you doing anything. (Nothing will **ever** be in `state.yourApi.data`!)

There are two full example applications with different ways of authentication implemented in the documentation under [Examples - authentication](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#authentication).

Please go take another look at those.

PS: also, please note that generally you should only have one single `createApi` call for your while application, so not a `authApi` and a `postsApi`, but just one `api`. You can still split those up over multiple files using the [Code Splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) approaches from the documentation.